# Start a nested for-loop at specific point

Tags: python

Say I have a nested loop

```py
for i in range(15):
  setup_things(i)
  for ii in range(16):
     do_very_expensive_thing(i, ii)
```

And I had an error at `i=9` and `ii=15` (Let's say very expensive thing is a database call and it times out and raises an exception deep in the stack)

How can I fix my ranges so that I can rerun `do_very_expensive_thing(9, 15)` and continue with `do_very_expensive_thing(10, 0)` and finish my loops without running anything I've already run?

I can't do

```py
for i in range(9,15):
  setup_things(i)
  for ii in range(16):
     do_very_expensive_thing(i, ii)
```

As that would cause (9,0) through (9, 14) to rerun.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. You can use the `while` loop instead of `for`.
Example:

```
i = 0
ii = 0

while i < 15:
  setup_things(i)
  while ii < 16:
    try:
      do_very_expensive_thing(i, ii)
      ii += 1
    except Exception as e:
      # log the exception for debugging
      # do recovery if possible
      # else just use pass
      pass
  i += 1
```

This will do your job.!

Comment: 2 Points: you can change the starting value at the top (so `i = 9` and `ii = 15`). Be careful with try except in a while loop. If it always fails at a certain point within `do_expensive_thing` you have yourself an infinite loop.